# Не могу уменьшить основной раздел с помощью gparted после уменьшения логических разделов lvm

Tags: linux, файловая-система, lvm, gparted

Нужно сократить размер основного раздела для записи образа на меньший диск.

Имею:

```
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                         772M  9.1M  763M   2% /run
/dev/sda1                     4.7G  3.0G  1.5G  67% /
tmpfs                         3.8G   79M  3.7G   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs                         5.0M  8.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--common  2.0G  3.1M  1.8G   1% /opt/some-common
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--game     12G  1.5G   11G  13% /opt/some
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--var      20G   45M   19G   1% /opt/some-var
/dev/mapper/vg01-some--log      20G   48M   19G   1% /opt/some-log
tmpfs                         772M     0  772M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Сокращаю разделы **/dev/mapper/vg01-some--var** и **/dev/mapper/vg01-some--log** до 16 Гигов с помощью **resize2fs** и **lvreduce**. На этом этапе все нормально проходит, файловая система в порядке, загружается система, **df -h** показывает по 16G

Далее гружусь с флешки, запускаю gparted, показывает что свободного места стало больше. Радуюсь. Пытаюсь сократить до нужного размера (в рамках пустого места), сохраняю - бам, ошибка - не хочет сильно сокращать, хотя когда стал сокращать понемногу, сократил где-то на 200 мегов, а дальше ни в какую - та же ошибка (к сожалению сейчас нет возможности приветсти текст сообщения полностью).

**Вопрос:**
Общая ли это проблема, если да, то что я не доделал? Может быть недостаточно сократить каждый логический раздел и нужно сократить саму эту группу **vg01**?? Тогда как это сделать, если и вправду нужно?

Пожалуйста, помогите с практической т.з., так как глубоко изучать теорию сейчас нет времени, нужно просто решить проблему - записать образ на меньший диск.

**Ремарка:**
Записал образ с этого диска на другой диск (не мЕньшего размера, как нужно, а такой же как первый) - все нормально пошло. Когда на втором диске пытаюсь сократить gparted'ом - та же самая ошибка, то есть делаю вывод что проблема не связанна с физической ошибкой на диске.

---

у меня в списке блочных устройств:

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
  /dev/sda2  vg01 lvm2 a--  58.64g 20.64g
```

Как назвать блочное устройство? Допустим /dev/sda3. Делаю:

```
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
  Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

Что делаю не так?

---

Прикладываю также вывод vgs и lvs

```
**$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize  VFree 
  vg01   1   4   0 wz--n- 58.64g 20.64g
$ sudo lvs
  LV         VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  gkt-common vg01 -wi-ao----  2.00g                                                    
  gkt-game   vg01 -wi-ao---- 12.00g                                                    
  gkt-log    vg01 -wi-ao---- 12.00g                                                    
  gkt-var    vg01 -wi-ao---- 12.00g  **
```

Comment: приложите к вопросу вывод `sudo pvs; sudo vgs; sudo lvs`

Comment: *pvcreate устройство* — указывайте то устройство, которе хотите подключить в группу томов. то,которое вы упомянули как «меньший диск»: *записать образ на меньший диск*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> нужно просто решить проблему - записать образ на меньший диск

это значительно более простая задача, нежели «упаковка» сокращённых в размерах логических томов (*logical volumes*, *lv*).

---

вообще «бутерброд», который представляет из себя *lvm*, можно (довольно упрощённо) изобразить примерно так:

```
+--pv1--+----------pv2----------+
|       |                       |
| +------------vg1------------+ |
| | +-----------+-----------+ | |
| | |    lv1    |    lv2    | | |
| | +-----------+-----------+ | |
| +---------------------------+ |
+-------+-----------------------+
```

здесь `pv1` и `pv2` — это два *физических тома* (*phisycal volumes*, *pv*). обычно это либо разделы (*partitions*) на блочном устройстве («диске»), либо даже блочные устройства целиком (если на них отсутствуют разделы как таковые). число два я выбрал лишь для иллюстрации — в *группу томов* (*volumes group*, *vg*) можно включить любое количество (доступных) *pv*, минимум — один.

посмотреть общую картину можно, например, с помощью программ *pvs*, *vgs* и *lvs*. вот примерный вывод для изображённой картины (размеры условны, даны для иллюстрации; *pv1* — это `/dev/sda1`, *pv2* — `/dev/sda2`):

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV        VG  Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sda1 vg1 lvm2 a--  10g   0 
  /dev/sda2 vg1 lvm2 a--  20g   0
$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize VFree
  vg1    2   2   0 wz--n-   30g    0
$ sudo lvs
  LV  VG   Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv1 vg1  -wi-ao----    5g                                                    
  lv2 vg1  -wi-ao----   25g
```

---

вначале у вас было так (*vg* я не рисую для упрощения картинки):

```
           pv1
+-----------+-----------+
|    lv1    |    lv2    |
+-----------+-----------+
```

вы сократили размеры пары из имеющихся *lv* (освободившееся пространоство обозначено точками):

```
           pv1
+-------+---+-------+---+
|  lv1  | . |  lv2  | . |
+-------+---+-------+---+
```

в принципе, конечно, [можно «передвинуть» *lv2* на освободившееся место](https://superuser.com/q/435075/454489).

но, раз ваша задача — перенести эти *lv* (в составе *vg1*) на другое блочное устройство, то наиболее разумно будет:

1. создать на этом новом блочном устройстве *физический том*:

   ```
   $ sudo pvcreate новое-блочное-устройство
   ```

   здесь и далее `новое/старое-блочное-устройство` — это либо весь «диск» (например, `/dev/sdb`), либо раздел на разбитом на разделы «диске» (например, `/dev/sdb1`)
2. добавить этот *pv* в вашу группу томов *vg1*:

   ```
   $ sudo vgextend vg1 новое-блочное-устройство
   ```
3. «освободить» *pv* `старое-блочное-устройство` от логических томов (это самая длительная операция — будет копироваться информация с одного *pv* на другой(-ие)):

   ```
   $ sudo pvmove старое-блочное-устройство
   ```
4. удалить *pv* `старое-блочное-устройство` из группы томов *vg1*:

   ```
   $ sudo vgreduce vg1 старое-блочное-устройство
   ```

Comment: ** Лучше читать в вопросе, здесь куда-то делся весь формат. **
у меня в списке блочных устройств:

    $ sudo pvs
      PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize  PFree 
      /dev/sda2  vg01 lvm2 a--  58.64g 20.64g

Как назвать блочное устройство? Допустим /dev/sda3. Делаю:

    $ sudo pvcreate /dev/sda3
      Device /dev/sda3 not found (or ignored by filtering).

Что делаю не так?

Comment: `/dev/sda2`, в колонке `pv`.

Comment: а **старое-блочное-устройство** тогда что будет?

Comment: это и есть «старое». то, которое сейчас входит в группу томов `vg01`

Comment: а «новое» — это то, которое вы подключили к компьютеру для переноса информации на него.

Comment: У нашего Админа идея такая: уменьшить доступный размер на старом диске, потом целиком склонировать образ на новый диск. (вместе с загрузочной областью и установленной системой)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42865/discussion-between-asianirish-and-alexander-barakin).

Comment: отсутствует инпутбокс в чате, поэтому пишу тут. А есть ли возможность переместить всю корневую область "таким" способом. Просто у нас там настроенные скрипты в системе, которые за пределами этих логических областей, возможно еще различные программы и драйвера для подключенных устройств.

Comment: "у вас на «диске» есть и другие разделы, вне lvm?"
Ситуация на диске в в вопросе http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/547173/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%83-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-gparted-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d1%85

Comment: по поводу присоединения в чате - так и не нашел кнопку справа "join". Может фаерфокс некоректно отображает? http://savepic.ru/10583713.png

Comment: Device     Boot    Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
    /dev/sda1  *        2048   7571455   7569408  3.6G 83 Linux
    /dev/sda2       16386048 139368447 122982400 58.7G 8e Linux LVM

Comment: нет ли возможность создать lvm на том же диске, пересоздать разделы меньшего раздела, перенести данный и уничтожить первую lvm?

Comment: да, упоминаемое в ответе `новое-блочное-устройство` может находиться и на том же самом физическом носителе. если на нём достаточно свободного места, конечно.

Comment: 1. я же написал в ответе: блочное устройство — это может быть **и** «диск»(«винчестер», «hdd» и т.п.) **и** раздел, созданный на нём. 2. *lvm* как таковой удалить невозможно. это всего лишь система управления логическими томами. можно удалить то, чем эта система управляет: логический том, группу томов, физический том.

Comment: О! Получилось! Огромнейшее спасибо за консультации!