# Не могу разбить жесткий диск на Fedora 29

Tags: linux, fedora, lvm, gparted

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Устанавливая Fedora29 напрочь забыл про разбивку диска(нужно поставить 2 дистрибутив рядом с федорой). Пытаюсь разбить с помощью Gparted и пишет (смотреть картинку), то что свободно 0.00 Б, и в результате этого разбить диск не вариант. Подскажите идиоту как разбить в таком случае.

Comment: Если уж вы использовали lvm, то для разбивки нужно использовать инструменты lvm, а не gparted

Comment: Можно просто выбрать другой флаг?

Comment: В каком смысле «другой флаг»? У вас там lvm, его или переразбивать средствами lvm, или удалять полностью и создавать всё заново без lvm

Comment: Если вы не знаете, что такое lvm, то вам вообще не следовало устанавливать lvm

Comment: Спасибо,видимо при установке случайно выбрал lvm.Тоесть единственный вариант избавится от lvm это удалить и заного поставить без lvm?

Comment: Да, ну или изучить, что же всё-таки такое lvm :)

Comment: Спасибо,попробую разобраться

Comment: lvm: [1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/LVM), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/547217/178576)